# Spring Tutorial почему ошибка?

Tags: java, spring, rest, java-8

Прохожу Spring tutorial этот https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Почему в классе BookmarkRestController в методе readBookmark при вызове 
bookmarkRepository.findById(bookmarkId) выдается ошибка что findById не 
определен в bookmarkRepository? 
А если вызвать bookmarkRepository.findOne(bookmarkId) 
или bookmarkRepository.getOne(bookmarkId)
то та же ошибка но с  orElseThrow.

Вот код метода:

```
@GetMapping("/{bookmarkId}")
    Bookmark readBookmark(@PathVariable String userId, @PathVariable Long bookmarkId) {
        this.validateUser(userId);

        return this.bookmarkRepository.findById(bookmarkId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookmarkNotFoundException(bookmarkId));
    }
```

BookmarkRepository:

```
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.nw.bookmarks.model.Bookmark;

public interface BookmarkRepository extends JpaRepository<Bookmark, Long>{
    Collection<Bookmark> findByAccountUsername(String username);
}
```

Spring Data Jpa 1.11.12.RELEASE

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу код объявления репозитория и версию используемого Spring Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `findById` появился в Spring Data 2, как и возврат `Optional` методами репозитория.